# System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime

Tags: asp.net, exception, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I get the above exception after downloading and trying to run the latest Ajax Control Toolkit.
I get the exception in ClientCssResourceAttribute.cs, line 28. Anybody else getting the exception?

Comment: +1 for the meanest looking Exception message I've seen in a while!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in the new version.

Comment: You aren't giving any information about the version you were trying to use or the version that you switched to that fixed it. In the future please provide some additional information so that other people reading may benefit from your solution, it may also help you get answers... if anybody is getting this from .Net 4.0 projects (after installing .Net 4.5) the "new version" might be this MS hotfix: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2748645